# Kendo Dropdown Panel Width

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a kendo dropdown list that I have Created in Jquery.

Markup:

```
$('.divReassignTo').width(150).kendoDropDownList({
   dataTextField: "Name",
   dataValueField: "Guid",
   dataSource: dataForAssignedTo,
   optionLabel: "Select..."
 });
```

The problem is that when for the first time I open the dropdown it's panel width goes little wider then the dropdown width but the next time it comes properly.

I want that first time also it should come properly.

In the below image you can see extraa width in first figure:
[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you demonstrate with a jsfiddle? I can't seem to repro.